# Upgraded to iOS 5.1 and xcode 4.3, now app won't install

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.3, ad-hoc-distribution, ios5.1

I have a working app. I updated from xcode 4.2 to 4.3 yesterday. ANd i updated my phone from iOS 5.0 to 5.1.

I build my app in Xcode 4.3, and while tethered, the app works just fine on my phone. I then delete the app from my phone, create an ad-hoc distributable in Xcode, drop the new app and distribution provisioning profile into iTunes, and then tell iTunes to SYnc.

The app transfers to my phone, and i watch it "installing..." but then it pops up the very helpful message " failed to install." I tried created a new distribution profile, but no help.

Comment: I experience the same. I just create a adhoc with the same certificates i used for xcode 4.2, and now i suddenly get the error "failed to install" when I try to sync with Itunes.

Comment: First I thought i needed by app to be valid, it had some errors in it. But it doesnt seems to matter. ad hoc just doesnt work in xcode 4.3.1

Comment: This Question solved my issue...Thanks @Gary Hilerson

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what worked for me in Xcode 4.3.1

- Go to XCode
- Open the project, click on the project file in the explorer
- Under targets, click on you project target
- Go to the "build settings" tab
- go to the "Code signing" section
- By code signing Identity -> release -> select the add hoc profile you created in the IOS provisioning portal ( provisions -> Distrubution )
- CMD - S ( save )
- Click on project -> archive and you can create your add-hoc

Comment: At first this didn't work for me, when i only changed the Release setting. I changed all of the code signing identity settings from "Developer" to "Distribution" and then it worked. I guess i need to learn more about those settings, which are one of the more confusing aspects of iOS development for me

Answer (score 4):

I was having exactly the same problem when I came across this topic. Melvin's answer above was something I had already tried, and I was sure I had it correct. Then I read the comment from Gary saying: "At first this didn't work for me, when i only changed the Release setting. I changed all of the code signing identity settings from "Developer" to "Distribution" and then it worked."

It turns out that Gary's fix worked for me too. But it isn't the solution, but it does point to the root problem. In my case, it worked because my "Ad Hoc Distribution" scheme was configured incorrectly. I suspect that is the case for Gary as well.

Here's how I fixed it:

1. Select your Ad Hoc Distribution scheme (e.g., use the Scheme button to select it)
2. Select "Edit scheme..."
3. Select "Archive" in the left-most column
4. Select the correct "Build Configuration" in the selection box (e.g., "Release" or "Ad Hoc" or whatever you named your Ad Hoc build configuration)

In my case, I had the Build Configuration set to App Store Release build configuration. So the archived Ad Hoc build was signed for the App Store. Naturally, when I would try to install it on an ad hoc test device it would not install.

Melvin's answer is also essential to fixing this. You must be using the correct code sign identity for your ad hoc build configuration.